# react-datepicker как выставить диапазон с одним пикером?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, datepicker

В соответствии с [документацией](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-21), выставить диапазон можно только используя два datePicker'а. Делается это с помощью пропсов startDate и endDate, которые меняются в соответствующих методах `handleChangeStart` и `handleChangeEnd`. Как бы мне реализовать это в одном `handleChange`?

```
handleChange = startDate => {
    this.setState({ startDate })
}

<DatePicker
    selected={ startDate }
    onChange={ this.handleChange }
    startDate={ startDate }
    endDate={ endDate }
    inline={ true }
  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что разность дат можно реализовать с использованием двух `DatePicker`, но не одного, пример:

```
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  selectsStart
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
/>

<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.endDate}
  selectsEnd
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
/>
```

Ссылка на пример из документации: [ReactJS Datepicker Date Range](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-20). Согласно документации, можно добавить к примеру `id` аттрибут ([General datepicker component description](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md#datepicker-component)), добавим его к пикерам и навесим один метод на обработку изменения значения пикера через `handleChangeDate` метод:

```
<DatePicker
  id="start-date"
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  selectsStart
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  onChange={this.handleChangeDate}
/>

<DatePicker
  id="end-date"
  selected={this.state.endDate}
  selectsEnd
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  onChange={this.handleChangeDate}
/>
```

Перепишем функцию следующим образом (согласно документации, вторым параметром приходит `event` внутри него есть `target` - объект, который отправил событие, у которого есть аттрибут `id` - прописанный нами ранее):

```
handleChangeDate(date, event) {
  if (event.target.id == "start-date") {
    this.setState({ startDate: date });
  } else {
    this.setState({ endDate: date });
  }
}
```

Это *грубый* пример того, как использовать один обработчик на два пикера, можно и другим подходом, главное - идея. Однако я бы предпочел использовать два обработчика на изменение через `handleChangeStart` и `handleChangeEnd`, чтобы не городить *костыльные* решения. Один обработчик, на мой взгляд, выглядит *костыльно*.

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал это, но в ТЗ используется один пикер, так что это не вариант. Нужно как-то в handleChange определять, что первый клик — это startDate, а второй - endDate. В этом https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1043 issue они про это говорят, но как это сделать — ума не приложу.

Comment: @ИгорьН в этом issue есть описание проблемы, но она в статусе `Open`, то есть пока решения нет. В вашем случае писать свой пикер.

Comment: Ну нет, просто функционал не реализован. Мне всего лишь нужно в handleChange первый клик записать в `this.state.startDate`, второй — в `this.state.endDate`

Comment: @ИгорьН Да, не так написал, просто функционал не реализован, вы правы, это не проблема а фича реквест типо. Вопрос: а разве у `handleChange` нет второго параметра в виде `event`? Первый параметр - это `date`, выбранный в пикере, а вторым вроде должен быть `event`

Comment: Есть, но у него `target: null`